# Integrality Test: Matrices as Homomorphisms of Modules

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

I am reading in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory book and I find an argument which I stumble upon in several places and which I do not understand. The discussion is fairly at the beginning and the statement in question is the following:

> **Theorem (2.2)** Let $A\hookrightarrow B$ an extension between commutative unital rings and $\beta=\{b_{1},\ldots,b_{n}\}\subseteq B$. $\beta$ is integral over $A$ iff $A[\beta]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.

The problem I have with the proof is the step where finite generation ought to imply integrality. For completeness I sketch the beginning of the argument: Fix a set of generators $w_{1},\ldots,w_{r}$ of $A[\beta]$ over $A$ and let $b\in A[\beta]$ arbitrary. By definition, we can find a matrix $\alpha=(a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq r}\in A^{r\times r}$ such that:
$$bw_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{r}a_{ij}w_{j}$$
Now the book says $(bE-\alpha)w_{i}=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$, where $E\in A^{r\times r}$ denotes the identity matrix.

My question now is the following:

> **Question** How do matrices induce well-defined maps?

I have the impression that unless $A[\beta]$ is a free module, a matrix defined using some collection of generators, need not be linearly extendible; that is I have not found out how to solve the following problem:

> **Question 2** Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module with generators $w_{1},\ldots,w_{r}$. Let $(a_{i,j})\in A^{r\times r}$ and define a map $\phi:M\to M$ by $\phi(w_{i})=\sum_{j=1}^{r}a_{i,j}w_{j}$ extended $A$-linearly. Then $\phi$ is well-defined, i.e. given $b_{1},\ldots,b_{r}$ and $c_{1},\ldots,c_{r}$ in $A$ such that $\sum_{i}b_{i}w_{i}=\sum_{i}c_{i}w_{i}$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^{r}b_{i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r}a_{i,j}w_{j}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{r}c_{i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r}a_{i,j}w_{j}\right)$$

The help I was given below raised another question. In proposition (2.3), Neukirch claims the following:

> Let $m$ a matrix in $A^{r\times r}$ and let $m^{\ast}$ denote its adjugate, then $mx=0$ implies $(\det m)x=0$ for all $x\in A^{r}$.

This is then used to deduce that $\det(bE-\alpha)w_{i}=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$. In order to deduce this, it seems that I would need that given a homomorphism $\phi$ with matrix representation $m$, the adjugate matrix $m^{\ast}$ also yields a well-defined module homomorphism.

> **Question 3** Why does the adjugate of a matrix representing a module homomorphism yield a well-defined module homomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your Question 1 is that matrices don't induce homomorphisms in general. In the notation of your Question 2, the mapping $w_i \mapsto \sum a_{ij}w_j$ can only be expected to extend to a module homomorphism for arbitrary $(a_{ij})$, if the $w_i$ generate $M$ freely. For a counter-example take $A = M = \mathbb{Z}$, $w_1 = 1$ and $w_2 = 2$, and try to extend $w_i \mapsto w_2$. In this example, a matrix $(a_{ij})$ will only induce a module homomorphism if $a_{2j} = 2a_{1j}$.

However, the part of the proof that you have quoted doesn't need Question 2 to have a positive answer. In the proof, you have the homomorphism (left multiplication by $b$) and you write down a matrix representation and that's OK - the matrix representation will necessarily satisfy any constraints imposed by relations between the $w_i$.

Comment: Ah, okay. I should know that homomorphism by now... Thank you very much. That is very helpful: my initial suspicion was correct AND the text I am reading is correct. That's the best out of several worlds.

Comment: Do you know an answer to Question 3?

Comment: I think there is a typo in your second quotation from Neukirch ("$(\det)x = 0$") and I don't know what it should say.

Comment: Sorry about that... It should say $(\det m)x=0$. The point (which I omitted) is that $m^{\ast}m=mm^{\ast}=(\det m)E$, where $E$ is the identity. In order to deduce the statement in the third question, I want to use $(bE-\alpha)w_{i}=0\Rightarrow 0=(bE-\alpha)^{\ast}(bE-\alpha)w_{i}=\det(bE-\alpha) w_{i}$, which requires me to know that the adjugate matrix is a well-defined homomorphism, does it not?